# fetch_bounces Cron Problem

Tags: wordpress, civimail, g-suite, bounce-processing

I have been having errors with the authentication for CiviMail's fetch_bounces. The error on the log for fetch_bounces reads:

```
Fetch Bounces   
Entity: Job Action: fetch_bounces
Summary
Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for return@****.org@imap.gmail.comError message: An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Could not selec (...)
Details


Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Fetch Bounces with result: Failure, Error message: Could not connect to MailStore for return@****.org@imap.gmail.com

Error message: 

An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Could not select mailbox 'CiviCRM': A0002 NO [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: CiviCRM (Failure).
```

When I look at the setup for the CiviCRM return account, I have the following setup:

[image: CiviCRM Return Email Setup]

When I click 'Save and Test' I again get the message

`An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Could not select mailbox 'CiviCRM': A0002 NO [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: CiviCRM (Failure). (See log for more details.)`

However, the email does exist on G-Suite and I am using an app password for a 2FA Google Account. This was working ok in the past. Any advice?

I am using the most revent version of CiviCRM (5.47.2) on Wordpress.

Comment: Is this the same as the first error in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41506/upgraded-joomla-civicrm-to-5-47-2-getting-deprecated-messages-on-system-status?

Comment: Possibly, he doesn't go into great detail there @MickKahn ... This is me testing out why it's not connecting with Google.

Comment: I'm also trying to set up OAuth for Google, but am running into problems there too - see this thread: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41512/problem-setting-up-oauth-for-google

If I can get that sorted, this thread might be no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've figured it out. In the option for *Source*, it was set to *CiviCRM* but I'd not set up the corresponding email box in Gmail. When I deleted it, it worked.